# change multi rows to one row-multi column

Tags: mysql

For some reason i have to do this. i have a query that have result like this :

```
limit     usage     tariff     total                  
0 10      10          700       7000                   
11 20     10          900       9000                   
21 30     10         1800      18000                  
31 >      11         2700      29700
```

the query return 4 rows maximum (like above) or sometime just 3 rows.
I want to change the rows to just one row and multi column like this (the list below just one row):

```
limit1     usage1     tariff1     total1   limit2     usage2     tariff2     total2               
 0 10      10          700          7000    11 20     10          900         9000       


limit3     usage3     tariff3     total3   limit4     usage4     tariff4     total4                       
 21 30     10         1800         18000     31 >     11          2700       29700
```

if the query return just 3 rows, the values in column limit4 until total4 will be empty. I dont know how to do like that.

**EDITED**

I add one ID column so the list will be :

```
ID   limit     usage     tariff     total                  
 1   0 10      10          700       7000                   
 2   11 20     10          900       9000                   
 3   21 30     10         1800      18000                  
 4   31 >      11         2700      29700
```

I try to make it one row like this :

```
SELECT e.*,f.id AS id4,f.limit AS limit4,f.usage AS usage4,f.tariff AS tariff4,f.total AS total4 
FROM  
(SELECT c.*,d.id AS id3,d.limit AS limit3,d.usage AS usage3,d.tariff AS tariff3,d.total AS total3 
FROM  
(SELECT b.id AS id1,b.limit AS limit1,b.usage AS usage1,b.tariff AS tariff1,b.total AS total1,
a.id AS id2,a.limit AS limit2,a.usage AS usage2,a.tariff AS tariff2,a.total AS total2 
FROM testtariff a 
INNER JOIN testtariff b ON a.id!=b.id 
LIMIT 1) c INNER JOIN testtariff d ON c.id1 != d.id AND c.id2 != d.id
LIMIT 1) e INNER JOIN testtariff f ON e.id1 != f.id AND e.id2 != f.id 
AND e.id3 != f.id 
LIMIT 1
```

it work as i expected for 4 rows but not work for 3 rows. should i use cursor ?

Comment: Formatting output in some specific way is the job of the application talking to the database, not the database.

Comment: Hi Dan, actually the list output from mysql stored procedure and it will feed another stored procedure that accept only one row.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally called a "pivot". Here's how you do it:

```
select
    '0 10' as limit1,
    sum(limit between 0 and 10 * usage) as usage1,
    sum(limit between 0 and 10 * tariff) as tariff1,
    sum(limit between 0 and 10 * usage * tariff) as total1,
    '11 20' as limit2,
    sum(limit between 11 and 20 * usage) as usage2,
    sum(limit between 11 and 20 * tariff) as tariff2,
    sum(limit between 11 and 20 * usage * tariff) as total2,
    -- etc
from mytable
group by 1,5 -- etc
```

This works because `limit between x and x` is `1` if true and `0` if false, so using multiplying by this is a simple way to filter the results into different groups.

Comment: Hi bohemian, i forgot to tell that the list is dynamic. i make some changes to display the list in my question edited.